# forEach while displaying graphs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs google charts.I want to display each column data from the database as one bar with rows as stacks.Below table represents the data in the backend table.

```
ID SPvalue  spstatus         name
1   30        recent         jtest
1   40        done           jtest
1   55        inprogress     jtest
2   80        recent         mtest
2   9         done           mtest
2   12        inprogress     mtest
```

Below is my js code.

js code:

```
$scope.chart.data = {
        "cols": [
            { id: "status", label: "Status", type: "string" },
            { id: "spValue1", label: "SPValue", type: "number"} 
            { id: "spValue2", label: "SPValue2", type: "number"}, 
            { id: "spValue3", label: "SPValue3", type: "number"}
        ]
    };
    $scope.loadDataToDrawChart = function(){
            myService.getResponseToDrawChart($rootScope.value).then(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.myData = response;
                        var rows = [];
                        var spValue = 0;
                        var spstatus;
                        angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(value,key){
                            spValue = value.spValue;
                            spstatus = value.spStatus;
                        alert("spValue : " + spValue + "spStatus :" + spStatus);
                            var myData = { c : [{ "v" : spValue ,"f":spstatus }
                                 ]};
                            rows.push(myData);
                        });
                        $scope.chart.data.rows = rows;

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** to get two stacks, break up the values into rows...

e.g.

```
      ['Month', 'ID-0', 'ID-1', 'ID-2'],
      ['jtest', 30, 45, 55],
      ['mtest', 80, 9, 12]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'ID-0', 'ID-1', 'ID-2'],
      ['jtest', 30, 45, 55],
      ['mtest', 80, 9, 12]
    ]);

    var options = {
      isStacked: true,
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**2)** to get separate stacks, with unique colors, use separate columns / series

each row should only have data for the series it represents

fill in the remaining columns with --> `null`

e.g.

```
  ['Month', 'ID1-0', 'ID1-1', 'ID1-2', 'ID2-0', 'ID2-1', 'ID2-2'],
  ['jtest', 30, 45, 55, null, null, null],
  ['mtest', null, null, null, 80, 9, 12]
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'ID1-0', 'ID1-1', 'ID1-2', 'ID2-0', 'ID2-1', 'ID2-2'],
      ['jtest', 30, 45, 55, null, null, null],
      ['mtest', null, null, null, 80, 9, 12]
    ]);

    var options = {
      isStacked: true,
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to create the data needed for **1)** above, see following snippet...

this should create a new row array for each change in ID,
if the same ID, it should add to the existing row array

```
function(response) {
    $scope.myData = response;
        var rows = [];
        var spValue = 0;
        var spstatus;

        var row = null;
        var id = null;
        angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(value,key){
            if (id !== value.spID) {
              id = value.spID;  // <-- had forgot this
              if (row !== null) {
                rows.push(row);
              }
              row = {c: [{v: value.spID}]};
            }
            row.c.push({v: value.spValue});
        });
        rows.push(row); // <-- don't forget last row
        $scope.chart.data.rows = rows;
}
```

---

**with test data**

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = [{"spID":1,"spValue":30,"spStatus":"recent","name":"jtest"},{"spID":1,"spValue":40,"spStatus":"done","name":"jtest"},
{"spID":1,"spValue":55,"spStatus":"inprogress","name":"jtest"},{"spID":2,"spValue":80,"spStatus":"recent","name":"mtest"},
{"spID":2,"spValue":9,"spStatus":"done","name":"mtest"},{"spID":2,"spValue":12,"spStatus":"inprogress","name":"mtest"}];

    var data = {
      "cols": [
          { id: "status", label: "Status", type: "string" },
          { id: "spValue1", label: "SPValue", type: "number"},
          { id: "spValue2", label: "SPValue2", type: "number"},
          { id: "spValue3", label: "SPValue3", type: "number"}
      ]
    };

    var rows = [];
    var row = null;
    var id = null;
    jsonData.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (id !== value.spID) {
          id = value.spID;
          if (row !== null) {
            rows.push(row);
          }
          row = {c: [{v: value.spID}]};
        }
        row.c.push({v: value.spValue});
    });
    rows.push(row);

    data.rows = rows;

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

    var options = {
      isStacked: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**edit with new data**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = [{"spID":1,"spValue":30,"spStatus":"recent","name":"jtest"},{"spID":1,"spValue":40,"spStatus":"done","name":"jtest"},
{"spID":1,"spValue":55,"spStatus":"inprogress","name":"jtest"},{"spID":1,"spValue":20,"spStatus":"done","name":"jtest"},
{"spID":1,"spValue":33,"spStatus":"donexx","name":"jtest"},
{"spID":2,"spValue":80,"spStatus":"recentxx","name":"mtest"},
{"spID":2,"spValue":9,"spStatus":"done","name":"mtest"},{"spID":2,"spValue":12,"spStatus":"inprogress","name":"mtest"},
{"spID":2,"spValue":59,"spStatus":"donexx","name":"mtest"},{"spID":2,"spValue":42,"spStatus":"inprogressxx","name":"mtest"}];

    var data = {
      "cols": [
        { id: "status", label: "Status", type: "string" },
        { id: "statusCount", label: "status1", type: "number"}, 
        { id: "statusCount2", label: "status2", type: "number"}, 
        { id: "statusCount3", label: "status3", type: "number"},
        { id: "statusCount4", label: "status4", type: "number"}, 
        { id: "statusCount5", label: "status5", type: "number"} 
    ]};

    var rows = [];
    var row = null;
    var id = null;
    jsonData.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (id !== value.spID) {
          id = value.spID;
          if (row !== null) {
            rows.push(row);
          }
          row = {c: [{v: value.spID}]};
        }
        row.c.push({v: value.spValue});
    });
    rows.push(row);

    data.rows = rows;

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

    var options = {
      isStacked: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: maybe i don't follow, what is the issue? the new data with the same code produces two stacks with five values each -- see latest edit above...